# How to add angular support for Notepad ++?

Tags: editor, notepad++, ionic-framework

I am building hybrid apps using Ionic framework. I came across to Notepad++ as an editor, but I found out it supports HTML and JS but there is no default support for Angular. Is there any way I can add support for angular.

**Note**: I am new to this Ionic (hybrid) development and I am unaware of any good editors for Ionic. If anyone has any experience or knowledge of some great editors for windows out there like eclipse for Java, I welcome that suggestion also.

Comment: Have you looked into JS plugins for Notepad++?

Comment: JS is supported by default

Comment: no, but I started using Brackets

Comment: I think vscode is the best thing for angular 2

Answer (score 6):

I can't answer how to add support in Notepad++. I used it once upon a time but there are so many other great options out there that have some level of support.

IDEs

- WebStorm (https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) This is probably the best IDE for JavaScript. It has built in Ionic and Angular support.

Text Editors - There are several plugins to add Angular and Ionic support for each.

- Atom (https://atom.io/)
- Sublime Text (http://www.sublimetext.com/)
- Brackets (http://brackets.io/)

Comment: Please mention when linked software is free/trialware...thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Notepad++ manage JavaScript correctly but you've to add some plugins if you want a better code.
This link gives me the basics plugins and personnaly, I would add emmet plugin
https://www.sitepoint.com/tips-developing-jquery-notepad/